# Interceptar error 404 con Spring

Tags: spring-mvc

Necesito vuestra ayuda...
Me han mandado capturar el error 404 en una página que está en uso. El proyecto es de Spring, pero no es mio y nunca lo había tocado, asi que no sé exactamente como funciona todo. Tiene hecho un controlador para manejar los errores, pero no captura el 404. He probado varias funciones pero no consigo capturarlo con ninguna. La idea es que al detectar este error te mande a una vista personalizada de dicha web. Alguien me podría ayudar con esto??

Os dejo un trocito de código del controlador de errores que tiene, para que veáis como los captura.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/error/json")
@ResponseBody
public ResponseEntity<String> handleExceptionJson(HttpServletRequest request) {
     return new ResponseEntity<>(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND);
}

/**
 * Trata los errores no controlados de peticiones que esperaban respuestas
 * xml.
 * 
 * @param request
 *            objeto {@link HttpServletRequest} de la peticion que contiene
 *            un atributo "exception" con la excepcion causante del error.
 * @return objeto de respuesta con el mensaje de error.
 */
@RequestMapping(value = "/error/xml")
@ResponseBody
public Object handleExceptionXml(HttpServletRequest request) {
    // TODO: realizar el tratamiento deseado (normalmente devolver un xml de
    // error generico)
    return null;
}
```

Espero que podáis ayudarme.

Un saludo!

Comment: Hay varias formas de resolver tu pregunta, pero puesto que tu aplicación ya incluye una gestión de errores, intentaría reutilizarla. Esos métodos claramente indican una redirección, averigua desde dónde ocurre.